# ConcurrentModificationException in a runnable

Tags: java, android, runnable, concurrentmodification

I am developing a timer manager that will allow multiple countdown timers and I cant seem to figure out how to avoid this ConcurrentModificationException. I have look at other peoples responses to similar problems but still cant figure it out.

```
mHandler = new Handler();

        mUpdateUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

        Iterator<HashMap.Entry<String, TimerHolder>> it = mTimers.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
   -----------> Map.Entry<String, TimerHolder> pairs = it.next();
                pairs.getValue().post();
            }

            Iterator<HashMap.Entry<String, TimerHolder>> iterator = mTimers.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                HashMap.Entry<String, TimerHolder> entry = iterator.next();
                if (!entry.getValue().isValid()) {
                   iterator.remove();
                }
            }                   


                mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUI, 1000); // 1 second
            }
        };
        mHandler.post(mUpdateUI);
```

---

```
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:843)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:841)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at com.watcher.timer.TimerManager$1.run(TimerManager.java:57)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
06-02 12:37:23.746: E/AndroidRuntime(10669):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/378/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-when-using-an-iterator

Comment: you need to use an iterator instead of a foreach loop.

Comment: Long story short, mTimers is being modified somewhere in your code while looping on either of these calls: for (HashMap.Entry<String, TimerHolder> entry : mTimers.entrySet())

Comment: On both foreach loops? @meh

Comment: you cannot remove any item from the list when using a foreach loop on that list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your issue is not related to concurrency. Your `Runnable` is always called from the same thread - the `Main` thread, because you post it to `Handler`.

`ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown because you tries to modify collection inside for-each loop. That's fail-fast behaviour in order to protect non-thread-safe collections from potential concurrent modifications. You need to use `Iterator` explicitly and call `remove` at iterator object. Your "deletes invalid entries" part should look like this:

```
Iterator<HashMap.Entry<String, TimerHolder>> iterator = mTimers.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    HashMap.Entry<String, TimerHolder> entry = iterator.next();
    if (!entry.getValue().isValid()) {
       iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. I tend to use for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) { if(removable == true) { x.remove(x.get(i); i--; } } for this type of thing. I can't tell if that's better than the iterator, probably not.

Comment: I updated the code above. I did what you said and it still does not work. I pointed to where it crashes.

Comment: Can you please add your `TimerHolder.post` method source code?

Comment: According to the fact that you keep getting this error you are modifying `mTimers` in this method, am I right?

Comment: It works now, I was actually modifying it somewhere else at the same time. I did need this iterator code though. Thanks an infinite!

Answer (score 0):

Some other thread is modifying the `mTimers` Map at the same time that your `run()` method is iterating through the same Map.

One possible (but not necessarily most efficient) way to work around this is to wrap the current Map instance in a synchronized map, and use the wrapped object everywhere:

```
Map mTimers = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
```

A synchronized map will synchronize the Map methods for you, so that only a single thread at a time can use the Map.

However, if you need to call multiple Map methods in a single atomic transaction, you will still need to do your own synchronization.